# Workflow for merging changes from a non-master default branch to master

Tags: git, github, aws-codepipeline, branching-and-merging

I am trying to implement a fairly basic CI/CD Workflow with Github to release changes to a dev and prod environment.

I have setup a new default branch in Github called `stable` (as opposed to the original default `main`). I also have rules to restrict users from pushing directly to `stable` and `main`

What I am trying to achieve is the following workflow for feature development and release:

1. `git checkout -b <feature-branch>` (HEAD is at `stable`)
2. Work on changes, `git commit`
3. `git push <feature-branch>`
4. Raise a new PR in Github to merge from `<feature-branch>` to `stable`
5. Once changes are merged to `stable`, auto-deploy changes to a relevant "dev" environment (eg. AWS CodePipeline integration)
6. After verifying/testing the changes using a combination of manual/automated workflows, kick off a merge of the changes tot he `main` branch
7. Once changes are merged to `main`, auto-deploy changes to a relevant "prod" environment (eg. AWS CodePipeline integration)

I have Steps 1-5 working. However, I  can't figure out an elegant way of achieving Step (6), aside from manually creating a new PR in Github to merge changes from `stable` to `main`. Is there any automated way to do this, for example, being able to merge changes to `main` from `stable` at a regular cadence, or by using some sort of external signal? Thanks!